# Compiled webpack node-loader incompatible libpixman library version

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack, node-modules

when I tried to run the webpack bundled file with node, I encountered this error:

uncaughtException: node-loader:
Error: dlopen(/dist/bb02f82da844aac4ac34c68b8d0bf068.node, 1): Library not loaded: @loader_path/libpixman-1.0.dylib

Reason: Incompatible library version: bb02f82da844aac4ac34c68b8d0bf068.node requires version 39.0.0 or later, but libpixman-1.0.dylib provides version 35.0.0

I need to use node_modules/canvas hence the use of node-loader

Is there a way to set specific node (loader) version while compiling so that the version can match?

Thank you...

Comment: ever found a way around this issue ?